# Prove that an algorithm has a lower bound

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, bounds

I'm trying to prove this problem:

> if an algorithm exists that can determine if a sorted list of n
>   elements has duplicate elements in it, than the number of comparisons
>   needed has a lower bound of `n-1`.

I'm not quite familiar with lower and higher bounds and I seem to confuse it, can someone help me with an easy to understand proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem statement is not rigorous. It should say "the number of comparisons *in the worst case*".

In a sorted array, there are `n-1` relations between pairs of successive elements, which are either `<` or `=`. If all elements are different, you cannot deduce the outcome of a comparison from that of other comparisons. Hence you cannot avoid an exhaustive search, taking up to `n-1` tests.

---

By the way, `n-1` is also an upper bound on the worst case, as after the exhaustive search you always have the answer.

---

In the best case, when the first two elements are equal, you find the answer after exactly `1` comparison. Hence, lower and upper bounds on the best case are both `1`.

Comment: doesn't this mean that if `n-1` is the lower bound of the number of comparisons, every other number of comparisons relative to the other cases better than the worst case should be bigger than `n-1`? which is not true because if a case is not the worst case it definitely takes less comparisons, this is what confuses me.

Comment: A question: does every case have a lower and upper bound, or are upper and lower bounds unique ?

Comment: No I mean does each case (depending on the input: all elements are the same, duplicates are found at the beginning, duplicates are found at some positions in the list etc...) has it's own upper and lower bound in terms of complexity, or does the whole problem of finding a duplicate has a lower and upper bound which is unique and independent of the input?

Answer (score -1):

If you have the array `list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`, you have to compare the 1 and the 2, the 2 and the 3, the 3 and the 4 and so on, to determine if it has any duplicates in it.

So the total number of comparisons is 4 and the total number of elements is 5 and thus `n-1` comparisons are needed.

Comment: Doesn't the algorithm stops when it reaches `3` and return `yes` after only `3` comparisons, how is `n-1` then a lower bound of the number of comparisons if there is a case where the comparisons needed are smaller than `n-1` ?

Comment: You did not address @aniani2020's objection.